# 1) NOT ABLE to create a foreign keys ON DELETE SET NULL, or ON DELETE CASCADE 2) Not able ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

I am not able to add foreign key constraint ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE.

I use two simple tables.

TAB1 has 2 columns: ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, and data int(10) unsigned NOT NULL.

TAB2 has 2 columns: ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, and FK int(10) unsigned NOT NULL.

I can create foreign key fron column FK in table TAB2 on column ID in TAB1 with "ON DELETE RESTRICT".

But i am not able to create such a key with "ON DELETE CASCADE" or "ON DELETE SET NULL". The errors is "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint".

I have tried with signed, NULL, int(4)... ets. Do not unserstand where is the error.

---

The only FOREIGN KEY(`tcfkowner`), which i managed to create with CASCADE a month before is in TABLE `tcalendar` ADD  REFERENCES tuser (`tcid`).

I unserstand that on DELETE CASCADE means that if i delete user, the row in calendar pointing to the user will also be deleted.

Instead the foreign key seems restricts deletion of his parent:  i am not able to delete any row in TABLE `tuser`  which is pointed by FOREIGN KEY(`tcfkowner`) from TABLE `tcalendar` . The error message:

" MySQL said: Documentation

## 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gintare_calendar`.`tcalendar`, CONSTRAINT `tcalendar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tcfkowner`) REFERENCES `tuser` (`tcid`))   " .

Answer (score 0):

Both fields - in master and in detail tables, must be the same; check it firstly.

Try this script to create tables and add foreign key -

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fk int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

ALTER TABLE tab2
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tab2_tab1_id FOREIGN KEY (fk)
    REFERENCES tab1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Or just try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fk int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_tab2_tab1_id FOREIGN KEY (fk)
  REFERENCES tab1 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Copying and pasting have worked and tables were created successfully, i just had to add the primary key to the second table. BUT actions does not work. For example, i need On DELETE SET NULL. I create table with this action instead of CASCADE. But hen i delete row in TAB1, instead of becoming 0 in corresponding foreign key field in TAB2, it is also deleted in TAB2.

Comment: If i drop foreign key. After wards i am not able to create foreign key on the same row with On DELETE CASCADE.  I am allowed to create only foreign key ON DELETE RESTRICT. What is the reason?

Comment: i am not able to create table with action ON DELETE SET BULL. I used your example above and created two more tables tab3, tab4 adding the primary key to the second and changing behaviour to " ON DELETE SET NU  ". The ALTER TABLE sentence gives error " #1005 - Can't create table 'gintare_temp1.#sql-1fee_bc5197' (errno: 150) "  If i try ON DELETE CASCADE - it works. WHy i can not SET NULL?

Comment: It is possible that you have NOT NULL column, check it. Also, just after invalid ALTER TABLE statement, run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS command, and view error details.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add ON DELETE SET NULL because setting field in TAB1 is set not null.
You can fix this by either changing your cascade or setting field to allow null value .
Hopefully help and sorry for my english